# chrome doesn't give access to web camera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, https, webcam, webrtc

The test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<video id="v1" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<script>
navigator._getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator._getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
    document.getElementById('v1').src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, function() {});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`chrome34.0.1847.116 m` doesn't give access to web camera if the page is opened over `http`, but it works if opened over `https`. That is, [the web camera icon](https://prept.co/img/faq/Chrome%20re-enable%20camera.png) (image from `google`) appears in address bar. I click it, select "Ask if example.com wants to access your camera", click "Done", then "Reload" in a bar that appears. But the video doesn't appear. It works right from the start if opened over `https`.

The webcamera is `Logitech C210`. It works fine in `skype`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it's not because you are trying to open your page directly from the file, not from a webserver and thus with a `file:///` prefix and not a `http(s)://` one ?

If the url in the bar address looks like `file:///...` then chrome will not allow access to the camera.

However if you launch your page through a basic webserver (`python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the folder where your page is) or with JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7Hkws/), it works perfectly fine.

---

In chrome settings, `Privacy > Content Settings > Medias` should be set to
`Ask when a site requires access to your camera and microphone (recommended)`

Comment: I'm sure, as such I experience the same symptoms at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Mmh, I have exactly the same Chrome version as you... Both jsfiddle and localhost works fine. Maybe you can try by checking your chrome confidentiality settings to see if something is wrong there.

Comment: Indeed, I had `Do not allow sites to access your camera and microphone` in `Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Media`. And if I switch it to `Ask when a site requires access to your camera and microphone (recommended)` it starts working. But `chrome`'s behavior is anyway strange, when it's forbidden to use camera and microphone. And then we still have issue with `firefox`.

Comment: Asked about `firefox` [separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251515/firefox-captures-video-noise-from-web-camera).

Answer (score 0):

This Answer is bit tedious but worth it for techies.Refer to this link and follow the Procedures.
Need to create a directory which will be used for Chrome In the Unsecured way and launch it by the command given in the link.

https://gist.github.com/jll90/5e0549ca5cce5d9c3a65600b29aab9a7

Command for windows OS
before this command create a folder on this location "D:\chromeInsequre" or at any other location with any name and replace the Path in Bold

start chrome --user-data-dir=**D:\chromeInsequre** --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com/