# firefox captures video noise from web camera

Tags: javascript, firefox, webcam, webrtc

The test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<video id="v1" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
<script>
navigator._getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator._getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
    document.getElementById('v1').src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}, function() {});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[This](http://www.screenr.com/b9xN) is what `firefox 28.0` captures. The webcamera is `Logitech C210`. It works fine in `skype` and `chrome`. The computer is running `windows 8`. Also, it works on other computer with `windows 7`. Filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1000892). Any thoughts?

Comment: Use latest browser, as this is a very fast changing field
Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia for guide on vendor prefixes and latest code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is fixed in [`firefox-29`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1000892).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try updating the webcam drivers or disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox, as mentioned in [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/953530).